# How to clean up my PATH

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

When I open a terminal session I get:

```
-bash: /Users/ftrflyr/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli: is a directory
PJP2:~ awjunior$ echo $PATH
/Users/ftrflyr/.rbenv/shims:/Users/ftrflyr/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/Users/ftrflyr/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/ftrflyr/.rvm/bin
```

Is this right? It seems like the PATH is all screwed up.

I am setting up my Rails development environment. How do I get my PATH back to the default OS X path? Do I need to do this?

Comment: Thank you Hambone. I was just going to fix that.

Comment: cat we see your .bashrc  Path setup for rbenv

Comment: Please read "[ask]". We don't have visibility into your startup files, and including them in their entirety in the question would be excessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the list of directories listed in your PATH:

```
/Users/ftrflyr/.rbenv/shims
/Users/ftrflyr/.rbenv/shims
/usr/local/bin
/Users/ftrflyr/.rbenv/shims
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/git/bin
/Users/ftrflyr/.rvm/bin
```

You can see there are duplicates:

```
/Users/ftrflyr/.rbenv/shims
/Users/ftrflyr/.rbenv/shims
/Users/ftrflyr/.rbenv/shims
/Users/ftrflyr/.rvm/bin
/bin
/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/sbin
```

Typically you want the directories for apps you added first, followed by a `/usr/local/bin` entry which will contain overrides to default executables, followed by `/usr/bin` type entries which are the default versions installed by the system.

You need to open ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile and look for anything modifying your PATH. We don't have visibility into those files, but they are where most modifications will occur.

As a developer you have to understand how your user-account environment works. I'd suggest doing some research on ENV and PATH to learn best practices.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will dig a bit deeper. I really appreciate your time.